# Google Cloud Instance IP change automatically

Tags: networking

We have experienced two server downtime in the past two months using Google Cloud Platform.

The first time, the server looks good in the console, but we simply cannot access it even Ping it from outside. We have to restart the server in the console and everything goes back normal.

This morning, we have another downtime and after we restart in the console, we suddenly found out that the external IP of the instances has been changed! But anything else is ok.

Does anybody else experience the same? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Ephemeral IP: An ephemeral external IP address is assigned to an instance for as long as the instance is still running. This means that it can change, which is probably what you do not want. For more, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ephemeraladdress